# Share clipboard across multiple Win10 PCs

Tags: windows-10, portable, clipboard, sharing

I am looking for a soft- or a soft- and hardware solution to transfer the clipboard from one Win10 machine to another. One of the two computers is only allowed to access certain addresses via VPN connection, no internet connection, 
but local LAN environment. In addition, I cannot install any software on this computer, but I can use portable applications.

- share clipboard
- Windows 10
- no Cloud
- no Installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ditto Clipboard Manager](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/) seems to be able to do what you want except the portable part. For the portable app you will have to look at [PortableApps.com](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/ditto_portable)

- Easy to use interface
- Search and paste previous copy entries
- **Keep multiple computer's clipboards in sync**
- **Data is encrypted when sent over the network**
- Accessed from tray icon or global hot key
- Select entry by double click, enter key or drag drop Paste into any window
  that excepts standard copy/paste entries
- Display thumbnail of copied images in list
- Full Unicode support(display foreign characters)
- UTF-8 support for language files(create language files in any language)
- Uses sqlite database (www.sqlite.org)

Comment: Ditto Portable looks great at a first glance. I can't get it to work yet, probably because of the strict security constraints I'm locked in, but in terms of the problem description, that's exactly what I was looking for.